# Kotlin equivalent for c++ class array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, kotlin

I'm trying to find the Kotlin equivalent of making a class array in C++

```
class Widget {
public:
  int x;              
  float w; 
}

Widget data[100];
```

Comment: A note for those who know C/C++ and want to learn Java/Kotlin.
In Java and Kotlin you can't just declare a variable, you must initialize it explicitly, e. g. `Widget widget;` in Java or `val widget: Widget` in Kotlin won't create a new Widget, `Widget widget = new Widget();` or `val widget: Widget = Widget()` would. Similarly, `val data: Array<Widget>` is just a varable, and `val data: Array<Widget> = Array(100) { Widget() }` is an array initialization, since arrays are objects too and behave identically. Also, Kotlin equivalent of Java's `new Something[x]` is `arrayOfNulls<Something>(x)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `class Widget` declared, you can create an array of 100 `Widget`s like so:

```
val data = Array(100) { Widget() }
```

The `Array` constructor takes two arguments. The first argument is the size of the array, the second one is the initialization function for creating its elements. In the example, I just call the default constructor of `Widget`.

Also, this initialization function receives the index of the element being created as a parameter, should you need that for creating your elements.

**Edit:** @Miha_x64 made some good points in the comment above, so I'll include some of it here as well.

You can also create an array without creating elements to put in it immediately, using `arrayOfNulls`.

```
val nullableWidgets = arrayOfNulls<Widget>(100)
```

This will give you an `Array<Widget?>` instead of an `Array<Widget>`, and initialize all of the array's elements to `null`.